# Comparing & getting values from two arrays in google script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

Here is the [input](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1mG4C.png),

```
colA = [1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3,3];
colB = [1.1 ,1.1 ,1.2 ,1.3, 1.3, 'ab', 2.1, 2.1, 2.2, 2.2, 'ab', 3.1, 3.2, 3.3, 3.3, 3.3, 'ab'];
```

- Both the arrays have the same length.
- if there are total 6 '1's in colA then there will be only 6 of the 1s item(1._) in colB.

I want the output in the console to look like:

```
1, 1.1, count of 1.1 = 2
1, 1.2, count of 1.2 = 3
1, 1.3, count of 1.3 = 2
1, AB,  count of AB  = 1
2, 2.1, count of 2.1 = 2
2, 2.2, count of 2.2 = 2
2, AB,  count of AB  = 2
.
.
.
//or something like this where I must get these three values.
```

Code:

```
for(i=0; i < colA.length; i++)
{
 for(j=0; j < colB.length; j++) 
 {
  // what to do here to compare the values.
 }
}
```

Should I go with two for loops because I want the code to be really optimized as there is going to be around 10k rows of data.
Open to any suggestions. Thanks for the help.

Comment: please add the data in text form.

Comment: I have edited the question. I hope this is what you wanted. @NinaScholz

Comment: come on how should s/b copy the data to try some code? btw, are the array connected by the same index?

Comment: I didn't get you earlier , my bad. will this help?  yes, they are connected. thanks.@NinaScholz

Comment: do you want to count `'ab'` different?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could iterate with a single loop and check the value with the successor and increment `count`.

If unequal make the output and reset count to one.

```js
var colA = [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3],
    colB = [1.1, 1.1, 1.2, 1.3, 1.3, 'ab', 2.1, 2.1, 2.2, 2.2, 'ab', 3.1, 3.2, 3.3, 3.3, 3.3, 'ab'],
    count = 1,
    i,
    length = colA.length;
   
for (i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    if (colB[i] === colB[i + 1]) {
        count++;
        continue;
    }
    console.log(colA[i], colB[i], count);
    count = 1;
}
```

Comment: Nice. But OP states `2, AB,  count of AB  = 2`.  Of course OP might not need that.

Comment: Perfect. Thanks for your valuable time. @NinaScholz